# More efficient and faster process time for Merging two sorted list C#

Tags: c#, nodelist

I have seen a solution in merging two sorted list given with this line of code bellow, but im keen to make it more faster and more efficient with the use of memory.

Any suggestion?

```
public ListNode MergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    
  if (l1 == null || l2 == null)
        {
            if (l1 == null) return l2;
            if (l2 == null) return l1;
        }
        ListNode newHead, p, p1, p2;
        if (l1.val < l2.val)
        {
            newHead = l1;
            p1 = l1.next;
            p2 = l2;
        }
        else
        {
            newHead = l2;
            p1 = l1;
            p2 = l2.next;
        }

        p = newHead;
        while (p1 != null && p2 != null)
        {
            if (p1.val < p2.val)
            {
                p.next = p1;
                p1 = p1.next;
            }
            else
            {
                p.next = p2;
                p2 = p2.next;
            }
            p = p.next;
        }
        //no need to use the while loop, directly append p1 or p2 to p
        //because rest nodes of p1 or p2 are already sorted
        if (p1 != null) p.next = p1;
        if (p2 != null) p.next = p2;
        return newHead;
    
    
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty efficient. The variable names could do with some work though.

Comment: For working code, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place you want to be posting.

Comment: that is very helpful, will check on that

Comment: If you the code works correctly, do please consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) on [codereview.se].  But please make it _complete_, including the definition of `ListNode`!  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".